# Files Window (Explorer view) Will Not Open from Unity Bar

Tags: 16.04

I just received a new laptop today from System 76.  It is running Ubuntu 16.04.  So far it is great, but I have found one issue.   When I click on the Files icon in the unity bar, nothing happens.  When I search for it and click on it, nothing happens. Just to be clear, when I click on the Files icon, I should see an explorer/directory type view of my file system.

Note, the other launcher icons seem to work fine.

Can someone learn me how to make this work?  I normally use ubuntu, but have never come across this one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't System76 support their products? If not right click on the Files icon in launcher > Unlock from Launcher. Then go alt+F2 >  type in `nautilus`  , press enter. If nautilus opens then lock the icon that shows up to the launcher.

Comment: I have not contacted System 76 yet, but will.   Right-clicking on the Files icon does not work either.  But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else comes across this, I often have this problem on 16.04.

I find that killing (-HUP) the nautilus process works for me.

i.e.

```
$ ps -eaf | grep nautilus
joe     2358  2115  0 Jan01 ?        00:00:11 nautilus -n
joe    15093 15084  0 08:08 pts/2    00:00:00 grep nautilus

$ sudo kill -HUP 2358
[sudo] password for joe:

$ ps -eaf | grep nautilus
jlowe    15100 15084  0 08:09 pts/2    00:00:00 grep nautilus
```

Now it seems to work.